# Display hidden input value in to Span

Tags: jquery

I'm not all that great with JQuery, but was wondering if anyone could assist me with my question?

Here's my following code structure:

```
<script>
var $e = jQuery.noConflict();
$e(document).ready(function() {
function displayNumbers(displayNo) {
$e('input[name="numberselection"]').val(displayNo); 
$e('#showchosen').html(displayNo);
}
});
</script>

   
<input type="hidden" value="" name="numberselection">
<span id="showchosen"></span>
```

The above code structure isn't working for me.

I am wanting to get the value of a hidden input on my website in turn for displaying the hidden input inside a  tag.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure it's simple to do! But I'm still very new with JQuery!

Thanks :-)

I tried writing out the following code snippet above based on bits of code references I've found online, but the code isn't working as expected.

**UPDATE:**

Apologises for any confusion

I am wanting to display the value from the hidden input below:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="numberselection">
```

In to the following :

```
<span id="showchosen"></span>
```

The hidden input on my website is being automatically populated with  numbers within the value="" parameter, which is working fine!

However, I need the numbers within the value="" parameter to display within the "showchosen" span. At the moment, the code I have above, isn't displaying my numbers within the "showchosen" span.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $e = jQuery.noConflict();
$e(document).ready(function() {


function displayNumbers(displayNo) {
alert('val change');
$e('input[name="numberselection"]').val(displayNo).triggerHandler('change');

}
var $hello= $e('input[name="numberselection"]');

    $hello.bind("change", function(x){ 
       
          $e('#showchosen').html($hello.val());
    }).triggerHandler('change');
displayNumbers(20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   
<input type="hidden" value="" name="numberselection">
<span id="showchosen"></span>
```

I have just call function with value.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! For some strange reason - i am getting the following error: "jQuery.Deferred exception: $e is not a function displayNumbers" when running this on my website - Not too sure why! Perhaps some other code is conflicting somewhere.

Comment: ok fine if you require any further assistance let me know.

Comment: Could I ask, should this code display the number which are in the value="" parameter? I can see that you've called a function to manually display the number, but should this code above be sufficient to display any numbers inside of the value="" parameter? - There was a confliction on my website which I've now fixed, no errors are displaying now - But I'm still not seeing the input, from the hidden input, which should be printed in to the "showchosen" span.

Comment: not able to understand can you please explain with example

Comment: Sure -  I'll update my question to show you what i mean :-)

Comment: just check updated answer